# How to join two tables based on the join condition result of two tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables lets say Student,Student State,Student Course
[Student](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPl41.png)
[Student State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX57L.png)

[Student Course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTHUH.png)

I have to join table 1 and table 3 based on the join result i get from table 1 and table 2. Which Mean i have to display course for the student only if he is in active state.
My Resultant table should look something like this 
[Resultant table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MllV1.png)

It should display course for only Active state Students, for inactive students it should it should not display their cousre but that record is still needed.

Can any one please help how to proceed with this

Comment: You have to same image for state and course

Comment: Can't you just add another join to the join of tables 1 and 2?

Comment: I am sorry corrected the image now.

Comment: You can have multiple JOINs in one query, and later JOINs can reference any tables joined earlier. `x JOIN y ON x.a = y.a JOIN z ON x.a = z.a AND y.b = z.b`

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really post your attempts, so that we can see what you have tried, and where you run into problems.

What you'd want to perform here, is a `LEFT JOIN`, using the student id as primary and foreign key to link the data between the tables. You want to put your condition in the JOIN statement that JOINs the course table with your other two tables, so that the courses only display for the active students. If you were to put a `WHERE` condition at the end, you'd end up filtering away entire rows, which is useful, if you wanted to retrieve everything from the active students only, filtering away the inactive students completely.

This is the SQL:

```
SELECT
  tbl_student.id,
  tbl_student.name,
  tbl_student_course.course as course,
  tbl_current_state.state as state
FROM
  tbl_student
LEFT JOIN
  tbl_current_state ON tbl_student.id = tbl_current_state.id
LEFT JOIN
  tbl_student_course ON tbl_current_state.id = tbl_student_course.id AND tbl_current_state.state = 'Active'
ORDER BY
 tbl_student.id ASC
```

[Working SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb9134/23)

Answer (score 1):

I use t-sql but if I get it right what you mean I am of opinion that you should use "left join" and put filter condition in ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `active` as criteria to your join. Then `left join` the id in StudentCourse to the id in StudentState.

**[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wRTz9VnfiabKmjsYD2Yrnp/0)**

```
SELECT s.studentno
  , s.studentname
  , sc.course
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN studentstate ss
  ON ss.studentno = s.studentno AND ss.currentstate = 'Active'
LEFT JOIN studentcourse sc
  ON ss.studentno = sc.studentno
```